# How to create menu section title in adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, menu, ui

I want to add section (menu items group) into adminhtml menu in Magento 2. Something like this:

[image: adminhtml menu sesions]

I've added file `./etc/adminhtml/menu.xml` with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Vendor_Module::section"
             title="Section"
             translate="title"
             module="Vendor_Module"
             sortOrder="50"
             resource="Vendor_Module::section"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

but I cannot see new section in the adminhtml menu.

Comment: Can you please update your whole menu.xml code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please update your menu.xml like below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Vendor_Module::section" title="Section"  module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="50" resource="Vendor_Module::section"/>   
    <add id="Vendor_Module::section-subsection"  title="Section"  module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="50" resource="Vendor_Module::section" action="section/index/index"  parent="Vendor_Module::section"/>    
</menu>
</config>
```

If is still not display please confirm that your module is enable

Comment: Element 'add', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Vendor_Module::section-subsection' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Za-z0-9/_:]{3,}'  .... Vendor_Module::section-subsection ... "-" is not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Please add like this in menu.xml

```
<menu>
    <add id="Test_Menu::parent" title="Menu" module="Test_Menu" sortOrder="100" resource="Test_Menu::parent"/>
        <add id="Test_Menu::test" title="First Menu" module="Test_Menu" sortOrder="11" action="router/controller/action" resource="Test_Menu::test" parent="Test_Menu::parent"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this below the `<add>` tag

```
<add id="Vendor_Module::section2"
             title="Section2"
             translate="title2"
             module="Vendor_Module"
             sortOrder="55"
    parent="Vendor_Module::section" action="vendor/module"
             resource="Vendor_Module::section"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

BEN1TH is correct, yet the wrong answer is marked as accepted with the largest number of votes.

```
Element 'add', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'Vendor_Module::module-configuration' is not accepted by the pattern '[A-Za-z0-9/_:]{3,}'.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208855)